# How can I filter directly a collection based on a value?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, filtering

I would like to know how can I get all the elements from a collection containing a specific value.

Like this:

```
@Override
public Collection<Sale> selectSales(String map) {
    HashSet<Sale> sales = new HashSet();

    for (Sale sale : salesList) {
        if (sale.getMap().equals(map)) {
            sales.add(sale);
        }
    }
    return sales;
}
```

But I would like to filter the collection directly. I read that I can do this using LAMBDA, example:

```
list.removeIf(c -> c.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE);
```

But I Don't know how to apply this example.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably something like `salesList.removeIf(sale -> ! sale.getMap().equals(map))`. Note the `!` for negation. However, that's probably not a good idea as this will modify the original list and hence calling the method with different parameters will probably yield wrong results.

Comment: BTW, is this your real code, and if so, is it intentional that you have a parameter `mapName` but then use some other variable `map` for filtering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a stream and `filter`:

```
salesList.stream()
         .filter(sale -> sale.getMap().equals(mapName)) // I've changed map to mapName as I am assuming that was a mistake
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

This **retains elements** which satisfy the provided predicate `sale -> sale.getMap().equals(mapName)`.

Note the above **does not** modify the source, if you want to modify the source then proceed with `removeIf`:

```
salesList.removeIf(sale -> !sale.getMap().equals(mapName));
```

This **removes the elements** which satisfy the provided predicate `sale -> !sale.getMap().equals(mapName)`.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that stream solution doesn't affect original list `salesList`, while solution based on `salesList.removeIf` (which OP mentioned in question) does.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, but IMHO `filter` is really the better way here, as using `removeIf` will probably yield unexpected results when the method is called a second time. Reasons should be mentioned, though.

Comment: I agree that stream solution is safer, I am just not sure if that is what OP asked for because of "But I would like to filter the collection directly" in question followed by `removeif`. Anyway since now answer also includes that case all I can do is +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the method name `selectSales`, you don't want to remove entries from the original list, you want to construct a new collection copying elements from the source and filtering out some values by a condition.

The condition is `sale.getMap().equals(mapName)`. Note that I used `mapName` instead of `map` which seems to be a typo.

```
salesList.stream()
         .filter(sale -> sale.getMap().equals(mapName))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming that `salesList` isn't `null`, a more robust version of the method would look like

```
public Collection<Sale> selectSales(String mapName) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapName, "mapName");

    return salesList.stream()
             .filter(sale -> mapName.equals(sale.getMap()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```